# current_user not stored in session on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a difference between dev and production (on a shared webserver). In my application controller I have these 2 lines as part of a method which stores updates:

```
@activity.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
@activity.update_attribute(:company_id, current_user.company.id)
```

In dev both the user_id and company_id are known and get saved in the database. This is because there is a before filter which stores the session info in the current_user.

But with the exact same code on the shared production server, it gives an error when it stores the record to the database and when I look in the log these both values are NULL. The error is:

```
"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'company_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `activities` (`activity`, `company_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('Test', NULL, '2011-12-09 09:01:29', '2011-12-09 09:01:29', NULL)):"
```

To me it seems on production the session isn't stored properly. I've searching around and the only think I can find is this article, which says you have to add "allow_http_basic_auth" to the user model. When I do that (I'm not using Authlogic by the way), then it returns this error:

```
undefined method `allow_http_basic_auth' for #<User:0x007f91990efce0>
```

Any ideas would be great!

Edit: in the application controller I have this:

```
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

    # Save new activity/update 
    def store_update(activity)
     @activity = Activity.new
     @activity.update_attribute(:activity, activity)
     @activity.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
     @activity.update_attribute(:company_id, current_user.company.id)
     @activity.save
    end
```

Comment: The error is from SQL INSERT, not UPDATE, is this the right place throwing exception?

Comment: The SQL INSERT error is caused by user_id and company_id not being set with the current_user values.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part from your before filter that should be setting the instance variable?  Also which session store are you using?

Comment: Start debugging by printing your session, something like `puts session[:user_id]` as the first line from current_user method, and rewrite your store_update method to use `update_attributes` instead of calling `update_attribute` multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not is the session, the logger showed correct session values just before saving the record. It now works by changing this:

```
@activity = Activity.new
@activity.update_attribute(:activity, activity)
@activity.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
@activity.update_attribute(:company_id, current_user.company.id)
@activity.save
```

To this:

```
@activity = Activity.new
@activity.update_attributes(:activity => activity, :user_id => current_user.id, :company_id => current_user.company.id)
```

And I'm not completely sure why...